# LINQ for IDictionary<TKey, TValue>? Is there an AddIf that I just can't seem to find?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, predicate

Basically, I was wondering if there already exists a way to do:

Right now I have:

```
if (func())
{
    dictionary.add(KeyA, ValueA);
}

if (func2(myString))
{
    dictionary.add(KeyB, ValueB);
}

if (anonymous predicate)
{
    dictionary.Add(KeyC, ValueC);
}
```

Does there already exist a way to do:

```
dictionary.AddIf(KeyA, ValueA, ...)
//etc?
```

I added `using System.Linq` but it isn't in there.

Comment: LINQ is kind of philosophically opposed to such a method.  LINQ is functional - which means no side effects.  This method is only useful for its side-effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing built in - I don't find this syntax intuitive but you *could* write your own extension method(s) to help you out:

```
public static class DictionaryHelper
{
    public static void AddIf<T, U>(this Dictionary<T, U> dict,
                                   T key, 
                                   U value, 
                                   Predicate<T> pred)
    {
        if (pred(key))
            dict.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

**Sample usage:**

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Predicate<string> predicate =  key => { return key.Length == 3; };

dict.AddIf("foo", "bar", predicate); //foo added
dict.AddIf("tooLong", "baz", predicate); //toolong not added
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with doing:

```
if (func())
{
    dictionary.add(KeyA, ValueA);
}
```

An `AddIf` will unnecessarily make the code more difficult to read - consider cases where the dictionary itself has predicates or functions as keys and values.

And yeah LINQ doesn't have an extension like you want.